# Samsung Smart TV App: setting video frame position (native player)

Tags: samsung-smart-tv

I am creating an application for the samsung smart tv that plays music clips in native samsung player. And I want scrolling in, so I must moving the video frame (player window). Here are come some problems:

1) Moving video on screen during scrolling is not fluent (On scroll event I get the position of element, where I want to have video frame, and set this position by function SetDisplayArea). Do you have any experience how handle this?

2) When I am scolling video frame out of display, top/bottom of video cannot slide out.
Is it possible show only a part of video frame (something like SetDisplayArea(0, -200, 400, 225))

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Which API version you use?

For API 2.5 to change player position and size `SetDisplayArea()` is the only solution for native player.

I haven't try it but if `SetDisplayArea(0, -200, 400, 225)` doesn't go out of the screen it is impossible to do.

Do you want to move player while the video is playing? You can't expect fluent animations on SmartTV platforms especially when you want to move huge (memory expensive) elements.

Possible solution for me will be to make image of your video player and make slide-in animation on this image. After that hide image and show real player instead and start playing the video.

Comment: I use API 2.5. SetDisplayArea(0, -200, 400, 225) really doesn't go out of the screen. So I must change the concept of application. Thanks for reaction

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be possible to use `SetCropArea()` in case of out of screen.